# Should I be able to compile reactive-banana-wx with "stack build" alone?

Tags: reactive-banana, wxhaskell

I cloned `reactive-banana` and tried to build the `reactive-banana-wx` example:

```
git clone http://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana.git 
cd reactive-banana/reactive-banana-wx
stack build
```

There is a `stack.yaml` in that directory, and it does fetch several packages, but stops with this error:

```
Progress: 16/20
--  While building package wxc-0.92.2.0 using:

[snip]

    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/kostmo/github/reactive-banana/reactive-banana-wx/.stack-work/logs/wxc-0.92.2.0.log

    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack5908/wxc-0.92.2.0/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack5908/wxc-0.92.2.0/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/setup/Main.o )
    Linking /tmp/stack5908/wxc-0.92.2.0/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/setup/setup ...
    Error: wx-config not found, please install wx-config before installing wxc
```

Is there some other step that must be performed before running `stack build`?

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34009800/105137) seemed to have a related problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says

```
Error: wx-config not found, please install wx-config before installing wxc
```

This error suggests that the program you ran cannot find the `wx-config` utility, which is part of the wxWidgets installation. One possible reason is that you don't have the wxWidgets library installed, which is written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

@Heinrich's answer put me on the right track.

I followed the directions [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/WxHaskell/Linux#Debian_and_Ubuntu) with some slight alterations.

On my Ubuntu 15.10 machine, I executed these commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc

# This seems to work even though my release's codename is "wily":
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0.2/ubuntu/ utopic universe'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++ libglu-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev libwxbase3.0-0-unofficial libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-0-unofficial wx3.0-headers wx-common libwxgtk-media3.0-dev libwxgtk-webview3.0-dev
```

I'm not sure of every one of those packages was necessary, but after installing them I was able to execute

```
stack build
```

successfully from within the `reactive-banana/reactive-banana-wx` directory.

I was not immediately able to run the examples; I first changed the line in `reactive-banana-wx.cabal` just under `flag buildExamples` from

```
default:     False
```

to

```
default:     True
```

Re-running `stack build` then compiled the examples, which could be run as follows:

```
stack exec Counter
```