# stack is unable to resolve dependencies instaling wx

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, wxhaskell

I am trying to get wx installed using stack. I don't have Haskell installed globally and use `stack new <app> new-template` to create a new project. Next, within the  directory I run `stack install wx` and get an error message:

```
In the dependencies for wx-0.92.3.0:
    wxcore must match >=0.92, but the stack configuration has no specified
           version  (latest matching version is 0.92.3.0)
```

Following-up the recommended actions and rerunning `stack install wx` a couple of times, the extra-deps list looks like this:

```
- wxcore-0.92.3.0
- wxc-0.92.3.0
- wxdirect-0.92.3.0
- Cabal-1.24.2.0
- process-1.4.3.0
- base-4.10.1.0
```

at this point, stack complains:

```
In the dependencies for process-1.4.3.0:
    base-4.11.1.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.4 && <4.11 
                  (latest matching version is 4.10.1.0)
```

and suggesting to add `base-4.10.1.0` again, but which is already there.

Q: so, how should I install wx?

Is it really that hard to get wxHaskell going? Should I start using cabal instead of stack?
I use the latest stack version 1.7.1 with lts-12.4 as the resolver.
A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009800/why-does-stack-not-recognize-the-dependency-it-just-installed) was posted back in 2015.

Comment: wxHaskell is not part of the current stack release; And you shouldn't try to use a different version from `base` (or `Cabal` and `process` for that matter) other than what's in the resolver. You can try to reconfigure with `--resolver lts-9.21`. LTS 9.21 had base 4.10, so that might work as long as you remove everything not wx-releated from your extra deps

Comment: LTS 9.21 gives the same problem. Guess it's time to start using cabal.

Comment: For me this works with `lts-8.16` and `extra-deps:
- wxdirect-0.92.3.0
- wxc-0.92.3.0
- wxcore-0.92.3.0
- wx-0.92.3.0`. Don't you have a constraint on `base` in the cabal file? Good luck, I remember I had a hard time to make it work...

Answer (score 1):

The hint given by [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%c3%a9phane-laurent) works! On my Debian 9 (stretch) I used the following steps:

1. Install the required libraries

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev libwxgtk-webview3.0-dev libwxgtk-media3.0-dev
   ```
2. Create a stack project with `stack new <app> new-template` and change to the `<app>` directory
3. Make the following changes to the `stack.yaml` file:

   ```
   resolver: lts-8.16

   extra-deps:
   - wxdirect-0.92.3.0
   - wxc-0.92.3.0
   - wxcore-0.92.3.0
   - wx-0.92.3.0
   ```
4. Run `stack install wx` and be patient!
5. Add `- wx` to the list of dependencies in the `package.yaml` file